# Qt handle process termination

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application that starts another application. I want to receive a signal, if the child application is terminated externally.

The code is:

```
CaptureApp::CaptureApp(int& argc, char** argv): QApplication(argc, argv)
{    
    launchDaemon();
}

void CaptureApp::launchDaemon()
{
    QString command = "daemon";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "somearg";
    process = new QProcess(this);
    process->start(command, arguments);
    connect(process,SIGNAL(stateChanged(QProcess::ProcessState)),this,SLOT(daemonDied(QProcess::ProcessState)));
    connect(process,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this,SLOT(daemonDied(int)));
}
void CaptureApp::daemonDied(QProcess::ProcessState state)
{
    std::cout << "DAEMON DIED" << std::endl;
}

void CaptureApp::daemonDied(int code)
{
    std::cout << "DAEMON DIED" << std::endl;
}
```

But no message appears when I kill child process. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `spaceNavProcess`? Why don't you connect the `process` instead? I also doubt that killing a process will trigger any signal.

Comment: @vahancho Sorry it was a mistake while copying code here. Originally names are ok

Comment: Is the daemon you are launching an actual, well written daemon? If so, it will detach from its parent. You could check that using `pstree` or `ps aux` to see if this daemon became a child of PID 1 (`init` or `systemd` or whatever). Side note: this is why Qt as  a `QProcess::startDetached()` specifically to launch daemons (or simulate a well written daemon, that will detach from its parent anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your example inherriting from `QApplication`, but in the first place it gave me this error:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot QApplication::daemonDied(QProcess::ProcessState)
QObject::connect: No such slot QApplication::daemonDied(int)
```

I then added `Q_OBJECT` to the class definition and it connected the signals/slots, but when I killed the process it gave the following error:

```
ICE default IO error handler doing an exit(), pid = 27773, errno = 4
```

When I however changed the class to inherit from `QObject` instead of `QApplication` it did work. So having the main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    CaptureApp captureApp(argc,argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

As commented by jbm, some processes stay attached, while others are not. I tried first `gedit` and it received a signal directly after starting indicating the processes had finished. Using `vim` however it did keep running and I was able to kill it externally.